# How do I pass the value of a HTML checkbox to Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, google-apps-script, google-sheets

## Question:

How do a pass the value (or state) of a checkbox created with Google's HTML service from the HTML (sidebar GUI in this case) to the Code.gs to perform a check against?

I have managed to pass all of the other data from here to the Code.gs. For example, the text box, the Date, the Text Area. However, as the checkbox has no "value" as such, I don't know how to pass the state.

## My Code:

(Not entire script as it would be too big)

In the HTHML:

```
<input id="complete" name="complete" type="checkbox" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function formSubmit() {
    google.script.run.transferUpdates(document.forms[0]);
  }
</script>
```

In the Code.gs:

(Again not entire code file)

```
function transferUpdates(form1){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Action Plan'),
      sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Problem Details'),
      actionnum = form1.actionup,
      desc = form1.description,
      check = form1.complete;
```

## Problem:

my problem is the "check" variable never has a value to compare as nothing is being passed over from the HTML form?

Does anyone have a solution to this?

(I am rather new to HTML so apologies if this is a simple answer)

Comment: What is the value of the variable `form1`?  Undefined?  Null?  [object Object]? You can print information to the LOGS with a `Logger.log('form1 value is: ' + form1);` statement.

Comment: Here is an answer to a similar question:  [StackOverflow Form Submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965495/html-input-required-attribute-fails-to-prevent-form-from-submitting-in-apps-sc/27966548#27966548)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to the element and pass value, etc. In your case of wanting to call a function server side try this.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
}

function getStuff(foo){
   Logger.log(foo)
}
```

index.html

```
<code>
<div>
<div id="mylabel"></div>
<input id="test" value="testing" type="checkbox">
<script>
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("change", changeit);
function success(){document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = 'success!'}
function changeit(){
  var v = document.getElementById('test').value;
  document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = v;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).getStuff("going IN")
}
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is manually set the checkbox:

```
check = (form1.complete) ? true : false; // false or true depending on checkbox
```